# Toast is crashing Application, even inside thread

Tags: android, toast

I have an onClick event in my android app that triggers the following code but it keeps crashing my app. I put it in a thread only because i read that that's supposed to prevent crashing. Also ctx refers to the Activity's context (it's a variable I created in the activity set equal to this. I've read and tried several things. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
Thread toastThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    Toast alertFailure = Toast.makeText(ctx, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    alertFailure.show();
  }
};
toastThread.start();
```

Comment: Post the logcat error please

Comment: In this instance putting it in a thread is what is making it crash. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3875204/833647

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Something like

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

`Toast` is a `UI` element so it needs to run on the `UI Thread`, not a background `Thread`.

However, if this is all you are using it for then you don't need a separate `Thread` just to show a `Toast`. If you can explain the context of how you are using it then maybe we can help with a better way. Also, if you are inside of your `Activity` then you don't need a variable for `Context`. You can use `ActivityName.this` instead to access the `Activity Context`

Comment: getting error cannot resolve symbol activity. Am I supposed to put something else there?

Comment: Sorry, I copied from something else I had and didn't change it quick enough. See my edits.

Comment: check this library `compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.5'`, it doesn't require `runOnUiThread()` or `Context` variable, all routine is gone! just invoke `Toaster.toast(R.string.my_msg);` here is the example: https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid-toaster-example

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't have your ctx variable instantiated, so you are getting NULL Pointer.

You should not put this in a Thread, and is actually a pretty bad idea (knowing you are just getting started).

execute: `adb logcat`  to see your log output.

Comment: How do I see my log in android studio? I just switched from eclipse

Comment: If you are a beginner, the docs even suggest not relying too much on Android Studio right now since it is a pre-release version. I would suggest sticking with Eclipse for your main development until you are more comfortable with Android development.

Comment: I don't know about Android Studio (and agree you should use Eclipse as a beginner).  You can issue that log command from the terminal prompt (outside of the IDE)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a different thread, your ctx variable is probably the one causing it, try using getApplicationContext(), this should work:

```
import android.widget.Toast;

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: you cannot show any UI related element in a non-ui thread which is probably why he is getting the crash

Comment: This is true, if you are trying to do something else than a Toast for example network related you should use **AsyncTask** otherwise your app will crash, although I'm pretty sure that if you are targetting ICS or JB it wont let you build the project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Only the mainthread can change the UI. That's why your application crashes. Do your work on the mainthread, and if you are doing something heavy like network or IO, you should use `AsyncTask` because each thread has 5 seconds to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help you.

```
runOnUiThread(()->Toast.makeText(this,"I am a Toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like this.

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Where:

- myButton is the id of your view
- myActivity is your activity

I hope this will help you.