# About Timer and Action...Help!!----(Android App)

Tags: android, timer, action

There are some problem!
I want to do some action after a second like change the words after 5 second.I set everything as well besides the setting of timer.

I think it is easy for everyone but i just pick up android 3 days.
What should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725. check this might help if you use a timer use `runOnUiThread` to update textview. you can also use a handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `AlarmManager` for repeating actions.

Example:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, YourIntentHere.class), 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pintent);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), iInterval, pintent);
```

So just encapsulate your logic you want to repeat in something wich is capable for an intent (Activity or Service).

Alternatively you could use an AsyncTask with Sleep, but I would not recommend sth like that.

See also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Comment: I am not going to repeat something.I just want to do a action like change the words' color after 5 second.Just do it one time only....

Comment: Actually, i don't know use this website.Can u give the link to me?

Comment: Maybe i am Stupid...:(

Answer (score 0):

For actions that are only done once:

**bad one**: start a `Thread` use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` and then make sure you are in the Ui-Thread again using `myActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` and change the Text again

**better one**: Use asynctask!
->

```
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>()
        {
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                // ui thread
            };

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                // non ui thread
                // do your first action here
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                // ui thread
                // do your seconds action here
            };
        }.execute("");
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, can u explain it more simply?

Comment: You can copy&paste this code in your app.
Then you can do Logic/Operations in the "onBackground" method.
Later you can display dialogs again in the "onPostExecute"