# Getting a NPE at timer task

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to execute a task every one minute in my application, I use the following for the same. The code is located inside onCreate method:

```
      mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PageTask();// The task I want to exceute every 1 minute. 
        }
    }, 0, REFRESH_TIME);
```

I am declaring the following at class level:

```
      Timer mTimer = null;
      long REFRESH_TIME = 10000;
```

However when I run the program I get a NPE at **mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()**

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Log Cat:

```
         07-29 15:57:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(15415):   at                                        com.Geet.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:93)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748): java.lang.RuntimeException:              Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Geet/com.Geet.CustomizedListView}:              java.lang.NullPointerException
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at              android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at com.Geet.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:94)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
         07-29 16:01:16.179: E/AndroidRuntime(15748):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you initialized the timer `mTimer = new Timer()`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have not initialized the timer

```
     mTimer = new Timer();
```

You can check this link as a side note

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725)

Comment: @Stacks28 i deleted the comment.

Comment: @Raghunandan :)np i was just saying u deserve +1

Comment: @Stacks28 thanks for your support i wasn't sure that comment was right. Is it against the rules?

Comment: @Raghunandan nope u can definitely ask for the same :)