# handler, I want to run periodically

Tags: android, handler, ui-thread

Using handler wants to run periodically The count is 0, if the countis 1, else  Please fix this code.

```
mRunnable = new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (count == 0) {
      setImage();
      count = 1;
    } else {
      weather = mContentResolver.getType(mUri);
      setWeather(weather);
      count = 0;
    }
  } 
};
mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code? Did you forget to call `mRunnable.run()`?

Comment: what is the problem buddy >?

Comment: @Raghunandan uhm... no problem but This code does not execute periodically repeated.

Comment: @AndroidKiller no problem but This code does not execute periodically repeated.

Comment: @JonghwanSeo did you call the run method?

Comment: What if I don't want to fix the code.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson he is the boss and he is ordering us to do so. So do it. :p ;). Else he will cut our salary.

Comment: @AndroidKiller what? You mean the rations fed to me by my parental units? Oh please no!

Comment: @JonghwanSeo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725. you can use a handler, a timer, a coundowntimer.

Comment: @JonghwanSeo check my post. it should work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below

```
m_Handler = new Handler();
mRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(count == 0){
            // do something
            count = 1;
        }
        else if (count==1){
            // do something
            count = 0;
        }
        m_Handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);// move this inside the run method
    } 
};
mRunnable.run(); // missing
```

Also check this

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725)

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank!!!!!!!!!!!!U!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i love u so much  @Raghunandan

Comment: wouldn't **m_Handler.post(mRunnable)** be better than **mRunnable.run()** ?

Comment: @gopi1410 yup you could do that( the android way)

Answer (score 5):

You should go for **Timer** and **TimerTask** in that case. Below is a small example:

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
        //put your code here
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
3000);
```

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: @Raghunandan i don't think handler is having any function to repeat the code periodically. Or is thr any ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725. check this you can use a handler also. Also you cannot update ui from the timer as it runs on a different thread

Comment: `setImage();` is probably setting image ie updating ui

Comment: In that case you can use runOnUiThread() inside setImage() method itself.

Comment: Handler we can use for sure as @altaf told in his answer. But that code looks repeatedly calling postDelayed which looks little weird but you can take my answer as another way of doing that. :)

Comment: everybody thank you so much .. i'm sorry that i dont speak english very well

Comment: @JonghwanSeo come on don't worry about that. This is not an english learning forum. So did u make it work in anyway ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller no .. yet I will make. Program that converts alternating icon and In fact, I'm a beginner Android so it hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.post(timedTask);

private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable(){

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   cnt++;
   if(cnt==0)
   {
    //set you view or update your 
   }

   handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 500);
  }};
}
```