# Stop Activity on Timeout

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting an `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` using `startActivity(intent)`, and then I start a `CountDownTimer`.
Now on timeout, I want to end `ActivityB` and have the `ActivityA` on foreground again.
Is it possible to stop an `Activity` from another?

Comment: you can use a timer task, count down timer or a handler call `finish()` when required.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725

Comment: **"Is it possible to stop an Activity from another?"** - No. As soon as ActivityB enters a running state, ActivityA will be in either a paused or stopped state. In a rarer scenario when system resources are low, ActivityA might even be destroyed by the OS. As codeMagic suggests, the best approach would be have ActivityB self-terminate. In saying that, however, I can't think of what it is you're trying to achieve and why you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Activity B do this -

```
 // 30 seconds coundowntimer 
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
       finish() // finish ActivityB
     }
  }.start();
```

Don't call finish on `ActivityA` when you start `ActivityB` or make it `singleInstance` otherwise instead of `finish()` call `startActivity(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class)` in `onFinish()`.

Answer (score 2):

Some code would help out tremendously to understand what you are doing. However, you could easily put the `CoundtDownTimer` in `ActivityB` and start it in its `onCreate()`. Then when it finishes just call `finish()` in `ActivityB` and as long as you haven't called `finish()` on `ActivityA` then you should get your desired result.

If this is not what you want then please supply some code and explain your issue a little better.