# How to delay code execution in Java? I am building a "memory game" in Java

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and I decided to build a "memory" game app on Android Studio as an exercise. So far I placed 12 buttons and the text changes when the button is clicked. Once two buttons are clicked, all buttons are disabled. I need them to be enabled again after 2 seconds. How can I do that?

This is the code that enables/disables all the buttons at once.

```java
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("btn"+i,
            "id", getPackageName());
    Button botton =   findViewById(resID);
    botton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a delay in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java)

Comment: The answers behind that link have the same issue as the answer below: This is correct for simple console applications or the like, but not for even-driven systems like the Android UI. Using `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread will make the UI entirely unresponsive (and probably not update) for the duration of the sleep. Suggested alternative: [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173).

Comment: I tried TimeUnit but it didn't work. the whole thing is delayed not just what comes after it

Answer (score 0):

I have just found something that seems to be working reading answers to similar questions.

Here's my new code

```
new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("tag", "This'll run 300 milliseconds later");

                for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
                {
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("btn"+i,
                            "id", getPackageName());
                    Button botton =   findViewById(resID);
                    botton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        },
        3000);
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Don't do what I suggested seeing as you're doing Android development. Refer to this post that may be able to provide some insight: [How to add time delay in java code in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316361/how-to-add-time-delay-in-java-code-in-android)

One way you could do it is:

```java
Thread.Sleep(12000); //12,000ms = 12s
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("btn"+i,"id", getPackageName());
    Button botton = findViewById(resID);
    botton.setEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: That's a bad idea in Android specifically and in most even-driven UI environments generally: This code has to be running on the UI thread to be able to interact with the buttons like this and the UI thread should never block (especially not for something like this, but even I/O should be avoided there).

Comment: You're right, just edited the response with some new information

Comment: This is bad on any of the common UI toolkits, whether its Swing, JavaFX, SWT, or Android.

Comment: Use a Timer, they have the right semantics for UI delay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700802/android-timer-updating-a-textview-ui

Comment: Thread.Sleep ... wouldn't work. it would freeze the whole thing for 3 seconds not just what comes afterwards