# update TextView every second with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I need tu update my TextView every second. I wrote it with Timer and TimeTask but everyone says its deprecated method.
Can someone show me how to make simple timer which updates TextView every 1 second with possibility stop it from UI?

Comment: why not use a handler

Comment: use handler to update the text view in every second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a handler or a count down timer

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something. update text view.  
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To stop

```
m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
```

Check this link for countdowntimer ,handler, timer

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725)

Answer (score 7):

No need to create a separate `Handler` for this (as in the currently accepted answer). In stead, just [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) the `Runnable` directly to the `TextView`'s internal message queue:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
    @Override public void run() {
        // do some work, then repost:
        textview.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
};
// post with an initial 1000 ms delay
textview.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
// or post without an initial delay
textview.post(runnable);
// or even run the runnable right away the first time
runnable.run();
```

Alternatively, if all you're trying to accomplish is to 'redraw' the `TextView`, use [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) (or [`postInvalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) from a non-UI thread). There are also overloads that allow you to restrict the invalidation to a specific rectangle, which you can potentially exploit for a more efficient implementation.

Comment: wow..awesome and so simple  !works for me !! Thanks  - I dont need any thread or timer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple handler to do what you need to do. Anyway, with the scheduler way you could do:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
...    

if(scheduler != null)
{
    scheduler.shutdown();
    scheduler = null;
}

scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
         // do your stuff...
    }
}, Consts.KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT, Consts.KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```