# How can I stop Handler in postDelayed mode?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

How can I stop the counter of the Handler when it shouldn't count anymore?
Maybe you can tell me how to do with the code below.

```
 public void handler() {
    nHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(8);
        }
    }, 20000);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `removeCallbacks`

```
nHandler.removeCallbacks(nhandlerTask);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

```
public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)

Added in API level 1
Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.
```

Comment: yes thanks, but what is nhandlerTask? Should be the runnable, right? But what is it in my case?

Comment: I didn't wrote more than I posted. Thats my Handler and it works, but I need to stop it and I don't know what I do with my Runnable.

Comment: you can also pass `null` and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer if it helps. If token is null, all callbacks will be removed.

Comment: @silvia_aut you could pass `this` or `null` yes it should be `runnable`