# android timer makes the app crash

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Timer that does something after 5 seconds.

Now in my main activity ( I only got 1 ) I wrote this class:

```
class Reminder {
Timer timer;

public Reminder(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        textFeedback.setText("test");
        timer.cancel(); 
    }
}
```

}

In a function (and also in my mainactivity) I create a timer as new Reminder(5).
After 5 seconds the application crashes.
I don't see whats wrong, because I do it in normal java apps like this.

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you have initialized `textFeedback`.

`textFeedback.setText("test");` cannot update ui from a timer task. Timer task runs on a non ui thread. Ui can be updated only on ui thread.

Your options use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread`.

Note runOnUiThread is a method of Activity class. Requires Activity Context

More info

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't pay attention that I updated the UI from a other thread.

Comment: @user1007522 check the link posted has a example of timer, handler and a countdowntimer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

Solved it like this:

```
         new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 //textFeedback.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 textFeedback.setText("");
             }
          }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

when the class Remainder is istatiate not know the var textFeedback , becaouse you nees to pass the owmer of the textFeedback