# Android Timer stops after 0,2 - 2 secs

Tags: java, android, timer

My timer looks like this:

```
runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (running) {
                            counter += 0.01;
                            String outputStr = String.format("%.2f",
                                    counter);
                            outputStr = outputStr.replace(",", ".");
                            display_time.setText(outputStr);
                        }

                    }

                });

            }

        }

    };
```

I start it like this:

```
new Thread(runnable).start();
running = true;
```

And I stop it like this:

```
running = false;
counter = 0;
```

The strange thing is that if I run my app the first time (code was changed and eclipse installs the new apk on the device) and start the timer for the first time it stops counting after 0,2 to 2 seconds. If I close the app (even through the task manager on my phone) this bug is gone. 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: you dont need a new Thread, just use a Handler

Comment: So I don't need to change my code in the first block ? How to call it without a thread then ?

Comment: @user3367856 You can use just the handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer

Comment: I don't get it. The guy from this topic uses a thread as well

Comment: @user3367856 the code shown in my previous link has a example of thread timer and a handler. But using handler in your case would do the job

Comment: @user3367856 use handler.postDelayed()

Comment: I changed my code to this, but the timer doesn't even start now: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VsPx6qSJ