# CountDownTimer Check every two seconds

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have one CountDownTimer and i want to do an action for every two wasted seconds.

```
countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {




            }
        }.start();
```

For example when it starts time remaining = 10 seconds

When time remaining = 8 seconds I want to do an action

When time remaining = 6 seconds I want to do an action

and so on......

Comment: You could use a Handler. Check Handler @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer

Comment: @Raghunandan would this be necessary? `onTick()` runs on the `UI Thread`

Comment: @codeMagic yes. Just my suggestion. Your suggestion will also work. Yes it runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if it is divisible by 2.

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      long seconds = millisUntilFinished/1000;
      if ((seconds % 2) == 0)
      {     // even number--do some action  }
}
```

This is assuming you are calling the `onTick()` every second like

```
countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
```

### **This is probably preferable for you**

Setting it up to call every 2 seconds should also work and better but leaving the original answer in case someone needs to call `onTick()` more often

```
countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 2000) {
```

then you could just do the action with every call to `onTick()`

[CountDownTimer Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onTick(long))

Comment: @noobProgrammer how do you know he downvoted? It was downvoted a long time back even before codeMagic answered. There is no way you can know who downvoted

Comment: @ataulm you are absolutely correct. However, the `onTick()` will be called at certain intervals depending on how the constructor is set up. I am assuming it is being called every second.

Comment: that's for every 2 seconds?

Comment: See my updated answer. I didn't notice your constructor when I answered. The constructor takes a `long` for millis...not seconds. You are calling it right now every millisecond which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @codeMagic I prefer the edited answer (+1); 1000ms is still divisible by 2 so the first answer wouldn't work - perhaps edit it to remove that portion (if you agree with my reasoning).

Comment: @ataulm I prefer the edited answer also ;) I got a little hasty and the original answer would take more checks.

Comment: @ataulm I have edited to make it correct. I think I'm done screwing up for now :P Thanks for catching that