# By starting a new activity, it starts again and again

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I set a textview, which I use for timer-function.
When the timer reachs my wanted time it should start a new activity, that set my Layout to another one.

```
textfield=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVTimer);
    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (Running){
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        number+=1;
                        textfield.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                        if (number>5) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uebung2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                    }
                } );
            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

That is the called class:

```
   public class Uebung2 extends Oberklasse {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Liegestützen1(2);
    setContentView(R.layout.new);

}
```

}

Now I am having the problem after the timer reached the time, which I want, my app is settin g the layout again and again for every second.
What is the solution to set the layout for once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
textfield=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVTimer);
boolean loop = true;

handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (loop){
            try {

                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    number+=1;
                    textfield.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                    if (number>5) {
                        loop = false; // this will end loop
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uebung2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }
            } );
        }

    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

beacuse you have place this

```
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    number+=1;
                    textfield.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                    if (number>5) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uebung2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }
            } );
```

inside your while loop.

also check your "number" value.

try your while loop as

```
 int i=1000;
 while (i<5000){
            try {

                Thread.sleep(i);
                i+=1000;
                }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
         }
```

and after this execute your runnable.

Comment: How can I change it? Is there any possibility?

Comment: @user3433232 you could just use a handler and gt rid of the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer

Comment: Close but `i` increases each time which will increase the sleep time. I don't think that's what the OP wants

Comment: i dont know for how much time he want to sleep its code. i guess he need 4 sec.

Comment: Using 1 second right now, `Thread.sleep(1000);`, so I would have to guess that's what he wants. I'm saying using `i` the sleep time won't be constant...it will be different each time.

Comment: then he just need to call thread.sleep(1000). no need for while loop.because of this in his code if (number>5) {} i thinked. anyway may be i guessed it wrong..:)

Comment: he can put his desired no.

Comment: The sleep time can always be 1s. I only have to change the number() of my code for example first 20s, next time 30s and so on. (Always)

Comment: then you can check for number in while loop.