# Call method after delay

Tags: java, android, timer, delay, stopwatch

I've crated Log in screen, and if user mistake 3 times i want to show timer of 2 min. I want that timer to be visually shown on the screen. I'll try this code and it's work, but I don't know how to display timer on screen.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 long waitingTime = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 min

 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
     //Do something after 2 min         
 }
 }, waitingTime);
```

Comment: Looking for a CountDown timer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer

Comment: this is fine work to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `Handler` called every second and update the UI during every pass. When you reach 2 mins you can cancel the handler.

Code should be like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
//class variable
count = 0;

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateCounter(count++);

        if(count < 120) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

And function to update counter:

```
private void updateCounter(final int count) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // you have the seconds passed
            // do what ever you want
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how about incrementing the count

Answer (score 0):

you need use runOnUiThread(Runnable action)