# Android TextView - Display Numbers Frame by Frame Showing Last Number

Tags: android, textview

I need to display a numbers(1-8) on single `TextView` like one by one and with sleeptime 1sec. here is my code

```
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `sleep(1000)` on the ui thread.

Comment: @Raghunandan how to i implement this can u suggest me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Handler` or a `CountDownTimer`. Do not call `sleep(param)` on the ui thread. This blocks the ui thread. never block the ui thread.

`Handler`, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Regarding CountDownTimer

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

You can find example of both @

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer)

Comment: is there any problem using this code. handler will run every minute, when we open the app.  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    if(i<9){
     TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
           txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
           ++i;
    }
    handler();
   }
  }, 100);

Comment: You can stop the `Handler` when you want to.

Comment: @sunil there i have mentioned in the last link. Check that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using handler.

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
int i = 0;

Handler handler=new Handler();  

handler.post(runnable);  
Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){  
    @Override  
    public void run() {  
        txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);  
        i++;
        if (i == 10)
        {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }  
};
```

Hope it helps.