# animateCamera, IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have separate map class in which I have written all the logic related to map activities as it was a strict requirement to keep both map related things separate. Now from main app activity I am calling function like this:

```
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mapObj.isLocationClientConnected)
                    Location currentLocation = mapObj.gotoCurrentLocation();

            }

        }, 0, refreshUserLocationInterval);
```

And in `Map Class` I have:

```
public Location gotoCurrentLocation() {
    currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, defaultZoom);
        gMap.animateCamera(cUpdate);

    return currentLocation;

}
```

But I get this error:

```
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at kbh.b(Unknown Source)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at lzd.b(Unknown Source)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at mbi.b(Unknown Source)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at fms.onTransact(SourceFile:92)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.animateCamera(Unknown Source)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(Unknown Source)
06-22 19:56:30.900: E/AndroidRuntime(11413):    at com.mapworlds.mapworlds.MapClass.gotoCurrentLocation(MapClass.java:176)
```

I want to keep the `animateCamera` in same function inside map class. I already have main context from main app available as a variable in this class, can I utilize it and make it work?

Comment: your timer runs on a different thread and you can update ui only from the ui thread. Use a `Handler`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, animateCamera modifies a UI component (the map), so that must be done on the UI thread.

**EDIT**

You can do this :

```
Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
             {
              public void run() 
              {  
                //update ui
                if (mapObj.isLocationClientConnected)
                    Location currentLocation = mapObj.gotoCurrentLocation();

              }
             });
           }
        }, 0, refreshUserLocationInterval);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `animateCamera()` from the main thread.

You can do so with a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), or [`post()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: I want to keep calling this function after specified intervals, can i do this with these?

Comment: @Maven yes, any of these will do.

Comment: @Maven Yes `Handler` would be a good choice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer. Note: `runOnUiThread` is a method of Activity class

Comment: @Maven Just be sure to create the `Handler` in the main thread (i.e. not inside `gotoCurrentLocation()`.